# Why a round Succah is not Dirat Kevah (permanent dwelling)?

Tags: talmud-gemara, sukkah, home-house, masechet-sukkah, maseches-negaim

> אחרים אומרים סוכה העשויה כשובך פסולה לפי שאין לה זויות
> Aḥerim (R'Meir?) say: A Succah built in a circular shape like a dovecote is unfit, because it does not have corners. [**and a permanent residence is one with corners**]. ([Succah 7b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.7b.18?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Tosafot&lang2=en))

The Metivtah does not have an explanation, but I remember the Mishnah in [Negayim 12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Negaim.12.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Gemmorah in B"B 164b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.164b.11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) that says a round house IS a house:

> תנו רבנן בית עגול דיגון טריגון פנטיגון אינו מטמא בנגעים טטריגון מטמא בנגעים
>
> (Tosefta, Nega’im 6:3): A round house, or one that is shaped like a digon, i.e., it has two walls, one straight and one curved, or one that is shaped like a terigon, i.e., a triangle, or one that is shaped like a pentagon, does not become susceptible to the ritual impurity of leprous spots. If it is shaped like a tetrigon, i.e., a quadrilateral, it becomes susceptible to the ritual impurity of leprous spots.

Why, to Aherim, should a permanent residence, and therefore a Succah, have corners?

Comment: That mishna in negaim say it is not a real house. Only a real house is susceptible to negaim uncleanliness.

Comment: @DoubleAA Where do you see from the quotes that this is not a "real" house? The gemmorah provides different forms of houses and nothing implies those are not "real" houses.

Comment: It is listing "houses" which are of insufficient standing to qualify as susceptible to tzaraat. That's the whole point of the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbeinu Chananel explains *Acheirim* is only invalidating a circular dovecot which is too small to fit 4x4 amos square (dovecots seem to be generally smaller circular structures than even the minimum-sized house):

> וקיי"ל דליתא הא דאחרי' דאמרו סוכה העשויה כשובך ולא כר' יוחנן דאמר סוכה העשויה ככבשן **ושמעתייהו כרבי סלקא דבעי סוכה שיש בה ד' אמות על ד' אמות** ולית הלכת' כוותי'.
>
> We don't hold like *Acheirim* and Rabbi Yochanan regarding a round Sukkah like a dovecot/furnace **who both hold like Rebbi that one needs to be able to fit a square of 4x4 Amos inside the dovecot/furnace**

So *Negaim* are not applicable even to a round, permanent dwelling incorporating a 4x4 amos square, because there needs to be 4 walls (which are lacking) Bava Bathra 164b:

> (בבא בתרא דף קסד:) למעלה הוא אומר קיר קירות שתים ולמטה הוא אומר קיר קירות שתים הרי כאן ארבע